# React: Cannot show button when element is true

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-props

this is my code:

```
const Agregar = ({inputPregunta, validatePregunta}) => {
  
  return(
    <div id="content">
      <h2>¿Cual es tu pregunta?</h2>
      <input id="valorPregunta" type="text" placeholder="Añade aqui tu pregunta..." onChange={(e) => inputPregunta(e)}/>
      {validatePregunta && <button>Agregar</button>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What i am trying to do is when the input has something entered the prop validatePregunta (default is false) comes to true and the button element shows, for that i tried to do a method in the App.js file like this:

```
actualizarPregunta = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputPregunta: e.target.value})
    
    if(this.state.inputPregunta.trim().length > 0){
      this.setState({validatePregunta: true})
    } else {
      this.setState({validatePregunta: false})
    }
  }
```

But nothing shows, is there's something that i am doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the code of the rendering for the props:

```
renderRoute = () => {
    switch(this.state.route) {
      case 'menu':
        return (
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Agregar inputPregunta={this.actualizarPregunta} validate={this.state.validatePregunta}/>
            <Publications />
          </div>
        )
      default :
        return (
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Publications />
          </div>
        )
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.renderRoute(this.state.route)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you update question to include the parental component code rendering `Agregar` so we may see how the state `validatePregunta` is passed as a prop, or try to verify `actualizarPregunta` is invoked in order to update state?

Comment: Added Drew! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you use the compoennt

```
<Agregar inputPregunta={this.actualizarPregunta} validate={this.state.validatePregunta}/>
```

you are passing the value of `this.state.validatePregunta` by property name of `validate`

and then you are expecting something `validatePregunta` in component `Agregar`, but it should be actually `validate`

```
const Agregar = ({inputPregunta, validatePregunta}) => { //incorrect

const Agregar = ({inputPregunta, validate}) => { //correct
```

OR else simply change the prop name as below

```
<Agregar inputPregunta={this.actualizarPregunta} validatePregunta={this.state.validatePregunta}/>
```

And you should change `actualizarPregunta` once you update the state it's not updating the state value real time, its a async process, so `this.state.inputPregunta.trim()` will give you the value just before the update, so change it like this, and i love the way @Drew Reese handle this part

```
actualizarPregunta = (e) => {
    const newValue = e.target.value;
    this.setState({inputPregunta: newValue })

    if(newValue.trim().length > 0){
      this.setState({validatePregunta: true})
    } else {
      this.setState({validatePregunta: false})
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue 1

The props don't align.

The component signature is `const Agregar = ({inputPregunta, validatePregunta})` but you pass `validate={this.state.validatePregunta}`.

```
<Agregar
  inputPregunta={this.actualizarPregunta}
  validate={this.state.validatePregunta}
/>
```

## Solution

Align on prop name usage.

```
<Agregar
  inputPregunta={this.actualizarPregunta}
  validatePregunta={this.state.validatePregunta}
/>
```

## Issue 2

React component state lifecycle. The enqueued state is attempted to be referenced within the same react cycle that enqueue it. You need the enqueued value which won't be available until the *next* render cycle.

```
actualizarPregunta = (e) => {
  this.setState({ inputPregunta: e.target.value }); // <-- state update enqueued

  if (this.state.inputPregunta.trim().length > 0){ // <-- current state value
    this.setState({ validatePregunta: true })
  } else {
    this.setState({ validatePregunta: false })
  }
}
```

## Solution 1

Enqueue the state update and use the current event value to set the other state

```
actualizarPregunta = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  this.setState({
    inputPregunta: value,
    validatePregunta: !!value.trim().length, // <-- *
  });
}
```

* *length  == 0 is falsey, length !== 0 is truthy, and coerced to boolean (`!!`)*

## Solution 2

Enqueue the state update and use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function to handle effect

```
actualizarPregunta = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  this.setState({ inputPregunta: value });
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  const { inputPregunta } = this.state;
  if (prevState.inputPregunta !== inputPregunta) {
    this.setState({ validatePregunta: !!inputPregunta.trim().length });
  }
}
```

Solution #1 is the simpler and more straight forward.